# chrome freezes after multiple download dialogs are opened

Tags: google-chrome, download, dialog, freeze

I have a button in my app that when clicked offers up multiple downloads. After the button is clicked, multiple "Save File" dialogs come up, and regardless of what the user does - cancel or save - when the last dialog is closed the entire chrome window (not tab) hangs. I can still type into the console, but letters and numbers only. Enter doesn't work, shift doesn't work. "Delete" key produces tiny red circles in the console. If I start some function that prints to the console every second before I do all this, it keeps running. So it's not a total freeze, but might as well be, nothing responds. I even tried leaving it when I went for lunch, still frozen when I got back.

This behaviour only happens if at any point in the process multiple "Save File" dialogs were open at the same time. It does not seem to matter how I trigger the download - clicks on < a > that point to a url, form POSTs that target an iframe, xhttp request followed by a.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(xttp.response). It does not matter if I do this programmatically, or manually click on the links or buttons. File types, file names, file contents don't matter.

Every approach that I tried has worked in firefox. The hangs happen in chrome. Tried on Ubuntu 14.04 and 16.04, 64 bit, up to date chrome.

I see only two options at this time. Ask the user to turn off the "Ask where to save every time" option. It works, but it's not ideal to rely on the user actually reading instructions, or asking them to change their settings.

The other is to forget this whole thing, and offer up a zip, which is also extra work for me, and for the user as well.

I don't believe there's a way to detect when a dialog is opened or closed, correct me if I'm wrong.

Thoughts?

Comment: I believe this was a bug in chrome itself, and it is now fixed.

I have previously tried generating two clicks on any download link on any site, and this would happen (so it wasn't an issue in my code). It no longer does.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an infinite Loop inside your script. Try Debugging step by step.